# Getting dynamic property value via string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dynamic object that is generated from [WebMatrix.Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data%28v=vs.111%29.aspx):

```
dynamic obj;  [WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord]
```

So doing something like this is fine:

```
int ID = obj.ID;
```

However, trying to access the property by string like this:

```
obj.GetType().GetProperty("ID").GetValue(obj, null);
```

and I gets the following error: `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`

I am assuming the `WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord` type is not used the same as the `dynamic` type? But it is declared as `dynamic`.

The following does return a type of `WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord` w/ a whole array of values:

```
obj.GetType();
```

However, the following returns a type of `dynamic` with value of `null`:

```
obj.GetType().GetProperty("ID");
```

I'm guessing that's why the error, but why is it null when `obj.ID` does not return `null`?

How do I get the property by string?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing that's why the error, but why is it null when obj.ID does not return null?

`GetProperty()` will look for a CLR property on the type. That's not always how a dynamic property access works - `DynamicRecord` derives from [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject), and I suspect it overrides the [`TryGetMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember) method which is used for property access (amongst other things). So basically, this is a property which is *only* available dynamically.

If you know that `obj` will always be a `DynamicObject`, you could always cast to that and call `TryGetMember` yourself... although you'd have to create your own `GetMemberBinder`. That's slightly awkward, but it looks like the only abstract member is [`FallbackGetMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487317(v=vs.110).aspx), so you'd just need to work out how to implement that.

Comment: Thanks, `obj` will always be the same type. Can you show me how to cast that into a format which can be used with `.GetProperty("ID").GetValue()`?  In other words, can I get this property by string, how?

Comment: @ZeeTee: No, you're not going to be able to use `GetProperty` on that object, because it doesn't *have* that property from a CLR perspective. If you know which properties you're going to potentially want, you could create an anonymous type with all of them, fetched dynamically: `new { obj.ID, obj.Foo, obj.Bar }` and then *that* type will have all the properties you need. We don't really know what your context is, which makes it hard to give more of an answer.

Comment: Ok, so I have to build my own object to handle this operation. Oh well, I'll take it as a valid answer. You almost have 1m points man! wow!

Comment: Actually, I was able to access the property by index like this `obj[0]`, so this resolved it.

Comment: @ZeeTee: That sounds like it could be fragile in the future... I wouldn't assume any particular ordering if you can help it.

Comment: I thought the same, but it looks solid.. They're sql column names, so the matching index to the `Columns` array always matches.